# Is it possible, from within a batch file, to get the name of the task scheduler task running the batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

In a Windows 10 environment, if I don't have access to the task scheduler that is executing my bat file, can I (from within the batch file) know the name of the task that has launched the batch file? Is there a variable that gets set with the task scheduler task name that I can use?

The obvious solution would be to add a task name parameter when calling the action in the task scheduler, but what if I have no access to the task scheduler?

Comment: On Linux/macOS you would probably be able to get your parent process id... no idea about Windows though.

Comment: What is the specific reason you're wanting this? Are you hoping to end a scheduled task which is running, probably under another users credentials?

Comment: You do not have access to task scheduler?? anyway, did you perhaps see what `schtasks /?` provides you with?

Comment: @Compo I want to do different things in my script, depending on the name of the task that started my script.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Nope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this solution works for you.

Below you can find:

a .BAT file and a .VBS that contains the function.

as for the .BAT:

```html
@ECHO OFF
SET DT=%DATE% %TIME%
SET DATETIME=%DT:~0,19%
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%r in (`CSCRIPT "C:\<your_folder>\current_task_name.vbs" "%~dpnx0" "%DATETIME%"`) DO SET current_task_name=%%r
ECHO script was executed by: %current_task_name%
PAUSE
```

as for the VBS named: **current_task_name.vbs**

```js
getMyTask WScript.Arguments.Item(0), WScript.Arguments.Item(1)

Function getMyTask(Cmd, StartDateTime)
 ' ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 ' Script to list all Scheduled tasks and their available properties
 '   Written for TaskSchedule 2.0
 ' ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Dim objTaskService, objTaskFolder, colTasks
 Dim objTask

 ' Create the TaskobjTaskService object and connect
 Set objTaskService = CreateObject("Schedule.Service")
 Call objTaskService.Connect

 ' Get the task folder that contains the tasks.
 Set objTaskFolder = objTaskService.GetFolder("\")
  
 ' Get all of the tasks (Enumeration of 0 Shows all including Hidden.  1 will not show hidden)
 Set colTasks = objTaskFolder.GetTasks(0)

 If colTasks.Count = 0 Then
  wscript.echo "No registered tasks."
 Else
  For Each objTask In colTasks
   With objTask
    'check if the time of execution is in the same range of the current task (~ 2 secs. after)
    If DateDiff("s", .LastRunTime, StartDateTime) <= 2 Then 
     Set objTaskDefinition = .Definition
     With objTaskDefinition
      Set colActions = objTaskDefinition.Actions
      For Each objTaskAction In colActions
       With objTaskAction
        Select Case .Type
         Case 0 '= Execute / Command Line Operation
          'If .Path of TaskAction object is equal to the batch file name provided
          'it returns its task name back
          If .Path = Cmd Then
           wscript.echo objTask.Name
           wscript.quit
          End If
        End Select
       End With
      Next
     End With
    End If
   End With
  Next
 End If
   
End Function
```

regards,
jtandrea

Comment: Not as self-contained as I was hoping for, but absolutely working for my needs. Thanks!

Comment: @user1030520, glad it helped!